# How can I put Windows-based video formats, or YouTube's MP4 format, from PC to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, file-transfer

How can I put Windows-based video formats, or even better YouTube's MP4 format, from my Windows PC to my iPhone? I have an iPhone 3G and whatever iTunes is on the net, and I have no idea how to do this seemingly simple request. Please do not close.

Bonus points (not really) for step-by-step instructions.

Comment: How can I move this question to the proper stack exchange site, if there is one?

Comment: You can try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have flagged this question as off-topic. http://apple.stackexchange.com/ would be an appropriate site for this question.

Comment: @IDWMaster, just move it instead of flagging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open iTune, click file->add file to lib, sync the system, u will see the media in your iphone's iTune.
maybe your iphone can not play the video for the format, you need a tool to convert the video to iphone acceptiable format, here is [a free windows iphone media converter](http://www.videora.com/en-us/Converter/iPhone/)

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how you sync the system, because the auto synch upon connect is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Actually this does work, but it gives an `iPhone synced to another iTunes library` message. How do I add it to my current library instead of overwriting it?